# Change the Text in an Android ActionBar Item Label

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In Android, is it possible to change the text label of an ActionBar MenuItem?
(Not using ActionBar Sherlock)

Comment: It seems strange to tag my question as off-topic AFTER it's been answered.  (I even accepted the answer before you marked it....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a reference to your `MenuItem` (probably most like in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`), then use [MenuItem.setTitle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), passing in either a `R.string.your_new_label` or a `String`. Then when you want to change your label, you can call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to trigger `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` to be called.

Comment: I already had a MenuItem (set up in onCreateOptionsMenu() -- is that the method you meant??) and a call to setTitle(), but none of that was having any effect (no invalidateOptionsMenu()).  After a bit of experimenting, I discovered that I needed to remove the title setting from menu.xml and set the MenuItem title in onCreateOptionsMenu().  After that, it's just a question of calling invalidateOptionsMenu() as part of any task that changes the MenuItem Title "input parameters".  Thanks!!